# Same Foreign Key Used for Multiple Unique Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quick question in RoR: Is it possible to have two fields use foreign keys from the same model?

For example, I am an employee. I want two fields: my current shop, and a shop I will be moved to in the future. In my model, how can I have two fields that are both the same foriegn key, but with different values.

It's hard to explain...

An example

```
EMPLOYEE TABLE
----------------------------------------------
Name        Current Shop ID       Next Shop ID
John Doe    2                     1 

SHOP TABLE
----------------------------
ID          Shop Name
1           Jims Tools
2           Johns Tools
```

In the `Employee` model, I want both `Current Shop` and `Next Shop` to be foreign keys from the Shop model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :current_shop, :class_name => Shop
  has_one :next_shop, :class_name => Shop
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :current, :class_name => Employee
  belongs_to :next, :class_name => Employee
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the foreign key doesn't match the table name, you just need to specify it. But you can have as many as you want.

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base 
  blongs_to :current_shop, :class_name => Shop, :foreign_key => "current_shop_id"
  blongs_to :next_shop, :class_name => Shop, :foreign_key => "next_shop_id"
end
```

The important thing to note here is, that you have to specify `belongs_to` in the model that has the foreign key. If `Employee` has a key that references a `Shop`, then `Employee belongs to a Shop`.

Same as if a `Comment` has a foreign_key of a Post, then the `Comment belongs to a Post`.